# htaccess with empty row in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Trying to mod rewrite (.htaccess):

http://domain.com/show.php?id=2
to 
http://domain.com/show/id/2
by use:
RewriteRule show/id/(.*)$ show.php?id=$1

and redirect user to error page if ( row[id] ) not exist in db, for now they see empty page without Value.

Thanks

Comment: The only part of this that .htaccess can handle is to redirect your static/SEO URI to dynamic format, as you've done. It knows nothing about whether id=2 is legitimate. You'll have to handle that within your PHP code, and do a `header("location: xxxxxx");` call to jump to an error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use for example something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ show.php?id=$1
```

and:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

.....mysql..

```
if (!$page_not_found) {
   header('This is not the page you are looking for', true, 404);
   include('your_404_page.php');
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite cannot check your database. You should check for an existing entry in php and redirect from there (or show an error message directly).